# How to create a partial-horizontal line in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a thin line below the main heading in a webpage, which is centered, something like [this](http://anunayk.com/). How do I go about it as using **/hr** will create an end-to-end line.

Comment: You don't. You can't. You use CSS. Also, you're example `/hr` is invalid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [your example](http://anunayk.com/) this is done with css and not with a [hr-tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)
So either you can use the css-style [border-bottom](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom.asp) as in your example, or you indeed can use a hr-tag which you give some CSS, e.g.:

```
<hr style="width:40%">
```

If you want to position the hr, you may need the [position-style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).
You can try this easily on the [w3c example site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_hr_test).

Remember, that the [hr-width-attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hr_width.asp) (not the style!) is not working under html5 anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can use  HR tag or HR tag with simple css code

Html HR tag :

```html
<center>Your Code Here</center>

<hr align="center" width="50%">
```

Here HR tag with simple css code:

```css
hr {
width: 50%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<center>Your sample code here</center>
<hr>
```

**Note:**
The attributes that aren't supported in the HTML5 spec are all related to the tag's appearance. The appearance should be set in CSS, not in the HTML itself.

So use the `<hr>` tag without attributes, then style it in CSS to appear the way you want.

Comment: @GCyrillus To be more precise, it's been deprecated and only obsolete since last December. The align attributes, too, have been deprecated and possibly obsolete.

Comment: There is no closing slash on the `<hr>` tag.

Comment: yes,sorry to use but here i just used to show hr tag visibility

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust HR width

```
<hr width="50%">
```

Or in the example you gave it is using css property of the div with a bottom border

```
#yourDiv {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Except the `width` attribute has been eliminated as of HTML5 making it obsolete. https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete

Answer (score 2):

you can restyle and add margin to your hr

```css
hr {
  border:none;
  border-top:1px solid;/* or bottom */
  margin:1em 15%; /* 15% or whatever fixed or % value that suits your needs*/
  }

body {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<h1>Any content before</h1>
<hr/>
<p>any content after</p>
```

width a fixed width margin is involved too

```css
hr {
  border:none;
  border-top:1px solid;/* or bottom */
  margin:1em auto; 
  width:17em;
  }

body {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<h1>Any content before</h1>
<hr/>
<p>any content after</p>
```

You can also use the border-bottom of any tag ...

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  padding-bottom:0.5em;
  display:table; /* to fit to content's width  else margin or a fixed width works too */
  margin:1em auto; /* if not display:table use width or margin values as first snippet */
  }

body {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<h1>Any content before</h1>
<p>any content after</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

---

CSS:
. hr {
  width: 50%
  color: #222
  }

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
     <h1> Your code </h1>
     <hr>
```

CSS:

```
       hr  {
       align-content : center;
       width : 20%;
       margin-left : auto;
       margin-right : auto;
        }
```

The hr style settings are to be done in CSS not in the body.

**Edit:** I used width to control the length of the horizontal line that will appear below my heading or text. Margin-left and margin-right :auto, automatically placed the line in the center where as normally the line would begin at one end of the page and end in another.

Comment: I used width to control the length of the horizontal line that will appear below my heading or text. Margin-left and margin-right :auto, automatically placed the line in the center where as normally the line would begin at one end of the page and end in another. I just noticing now all the errors in my code, so sorry

Comment: add this to answer body by pressing `Edit` link